# Apache2 + PHP5-FPM idle timeout when executing cli script

Tags: php, apache, apache2, fastcgi

Today I've switched from Apache mpm_prefork + mod_php to Apache mpm_event + php5-fpm. Everything is fine until cron job executing php cli script is launched. When I try to access any website hosted on my server I get error 500 and in apache logs I see

```
FastCGI: comm with server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi" aborted: idle timeout (30 sec)
```

When I terminate executing cli script and restart php5-fpm service everything is fine again. Any clues what can cause this issue? I will appreciate any help. Thanks!

**EDIT**

After some investigations I found out that it's not cli script fault. Cli script sends email campaigns using Amazon SES. I have SNS sendpoint on the same server and for each email I get notification. Few minutes after starting sending emails server is receiving 100s of SNS notifications. On mod_status page I noticed each SNS request is being processed for a very long time. In error logs there're entries I mentioned above (idle timeout), but I don't see any entries in slow logs (request should be saved to slow logs if it takes longer than 29 seconds). Any ideas?